# Rebalance data after adding nodes

Tags: nosql, cassandra

I'm using `Cassandra 2.0.4` (with `vnodes`) and 2 days ago I added 2 nodes (`.210` and `.195`.) I expected Cassandra to redistribute the existing data automatically, but today I still find this `nodetool status`

[image: nodetool status]

Issuing a `nodetool repair` on any of the nodes doesn't do anything either (the repair finishes within seconds.) The logs state that the repair is being executed as expected, but after `preparing the repair plan` it pretty much instantly finishes executing said plan.

Was I wrong to assume the existing data would be redistributed at all, or is something wrong? And if that isn't the case; how do I manually 'rebalance' the data?

Worth noting: I seem to have lost some data after adding this new nodes. Issuing a select on certain keys only returns data from the last couple of days rather than weeks, this makes me think the data is saved on `.92` while Cassandra queries for it on one of the new servers. But that's really just an uneducated guess, I may have simple broken something during all of my trial & error tests meaning the data is actually gone (even though I don't issue deletes, ever.)

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: There is no Cassandra 2.4. Which version are you using?

Comment: @Richard Sorry, 2.0.4

Comment: @natli did you get your data back? I am also facing similar problem.

Comment: @Hitesh nope, I gave up & reset the cluster entirely so I could rebuild from the original data. Many weeks wasted & I no longer have confidence in expanding a cassandra cluster on-the-fly.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no manual rebalance option for vnode-enabled clusters.

But your cluster doesn't look unbalanced based on the nodetool status output you show.  I'm curious as to why node .88 has only 64 tokens compared to the others but that isn't a problem per se.  When a cluster is smaller there will be a slight variance in the balance of data across the nodes.

As for the data issues, you can try running nodetool repair -pr around the nodes in the ring and then nodetool cleanup and see if that helps.

Comment: I manually set the .88 server to take less tokens because it's a weaker server. How can the cluster not look unbalanced if .92 has 44GB while the 2 new nodes, of equal capacity, only have ~200MB? Also, as I mentioned in the question, nodetool repair doesn't actually do anything. It prepares a repair plan and then finishes immediately, I really don't know what else to try.